# How to specify constraints for sap.m.DatePicker?

Tags: sapui5

[This](https://jsbin.com/rufosonosi/edit?html,output) is how we specify `minimum` / `maximum` constraint for DatePicker within *controller.js*.
But how to do this within XML view?

Below code within XML is not working.

```xml
<DatePicker id="dp" value="{
  path: '/val',
  type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
  formatOptions: {
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    strictParsing: 'true'
  },
  constraints: {
    minimum: '/min',
    maximum: '/max'
  }
}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no binding support (and [won't be](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130#issuecomment-320278250) any) inside another binding definition which is why binding paths such as `'/min'` or `'/max'` in constraints are invalid. It's just not possible because only modules, which extend from [MananagedObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject), support data binding features.

Therefore, such definitions must be done in JS outside of the XML view. One of such workarounds would be to call a high level API of `bindProperty` on the control instance (in our case, [`bindValue`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.InputBase#methods/bindValue)) while you can keep the control settings in the XML view.

```xml
<DatePicker id="dp"/>
```

```js
this.byId("dp").bindValue({
  path: "/val",
  type: "sap.ui.model.type.Date",
  formatOptions: { /*...*/ },  
  constraints: {
    minimum: myModel.getProperty("/min"),
    maximum: myModel.getProperty("/max"),
  },
});
```

**Alternatively,** you can keep the binding path in the XML view and set only the binding [type (Date)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.type.Date) in JS **with [`setType`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.PropertyBinding#methods/setType) from the `value`-PropertyBinding instance**:

```xml
<DatePicker id="dp" value="{/val}"/>
```

```js
// `DateType` required from "sap/ui/model/type/Date"
const type = new DateType({
  // formatOptions
  pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd",
  strictParsing: true,
}, {
  // constraints
  minimum: myModel.getProperty("/min"),
  maximum: myModel.getProperty("/max"),
});
this.byId("dp").getBinding("value").setType(type, "string");
```

The second argument of `setType` is the name of the JS type of the `value` property, aka "internal type". In this case, it's `"string"`.

> The internal type is the property type of the element which the value is formatted to.

Comment: How can we do the same in XML view? I mean How can we set the constraints with view model?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari As mentioned in the answer, neither binding model data to the `constraints` nor assigning model data to it from the XMLView is supported.

Comment: Even in controller is not possible?

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari You can **assign** model data to the `constraints` in the controller (as shown in the answer), but [binding is not supported](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130#issuecomment-320278250) since the [type modules](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Type) are not derived from ManagedObject which handles binding. Even if they are, all controls should somehow have an additional aggregation to enable "type" binding.